# Upgrading Bootstrap

Tags: css, .net, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend, razor-pages

I'm upgrading bootstrap 3.3.6 to 3.4.1. First need to first I need to find all the places(HTML elements) that use bootstrap 3.3.6 so I can do my regression testing covering those elements. Is there a way I can find all the bootstrap references?

This is a .net application with razor views
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via search text feature in your IDE like CTRL + Shift + F in visual Studio and Rider (assume it set Visual Studio Key-map), Which provides you with tools such :

- Preview of codes before navigate to it.
- Search a term in specific files (.cs, .cs-html, ...).
- Search a term with regular expression.
- ...

For example assume we need to find all div which is have row class ( my IDE is rider), so all you can do, after open "find in files" popup, is just set simple things like image below:

[image]

Comment: This only helps when you know what classes are being used. I want to find all the elements that have bootstrap's styling.

Comment: I'm sorry, it can't help you. it seems your problem is different and i have no idea about it. @Ash